# Graph API v2.1 Upgrade Notice - android

Tags: android

I've just received the following from Facebook:

**Graph API v2.1 Upgrade Notice**

[image: Graph API v2.1 Upgrade Notice]

I have no idea what any of this means.
Anyone got any ideas? Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory to me. You're using an old API version. Stop that, and use the new one.

Comment: Please read the How to ask page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much Robin, I will follow you advice to ask clearly.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing new API v.2.6, Thank you Robin.

Answer (score 0):

> I solved the problem by changing new API v.2.6, Thank you Robin. @Win Ko Ko

Case closed by the OP in the comments.  If you need more information, there are links to an upgrade tool right in the message, and there is a change log to tell what might need to be altered before the cutoff date of August 8th.

In my case, my app wasn't making any real calls to the old API and no changes are supposed to be needed even though I received this message.  This is still pending further investigation and will be updated to confirm that this message can be a false positive of a problem.